# Finding an orthogonal $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ so that $D=P^tAP$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given some matrix $A$, how do I find a diagonal matrix $D$ and an orthogonal $P$ so that $D = P^t A P$?
I know how it's done with a regular $P$ which is invertible, how is it different with $P$ is orthogonal?

Comment: This isn't always possible. Even if $A$ is assumed to be diagonalizable, it's not always possible. But if it possible, you just have to find $P$ in the usual way and then you apply G.S. to its columns.

Comment: You can do this if and only if $A$ is (real) symmetric.

Comment: You can also do something very similar if $A$ is (complex) Hermitian (i.e., $\overline{A}^t = A$), in which case one can find a unitary matrix $P$ (i.e., $P^{-1} = \overline{P}^t$) with $D = \overline{P}^t A P$ a diagonal matrix.  (here, $\overline{a+ib} = a-ib$ is complex conjugation)